# Some websites not allowed to be parsed by xpath?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am trying to parse one element from a website that is inside of a table.  This is the exact xpath expression that I use:

```
[xpathParser search:@"/table[1]/tr[2]/td[1]"];
```

However, when I run the program, my string comes up empty.  I'm wondering if the site is blocking me from parsing, or whether my expression is correct.  If it helps, this is the site, and the piece I am trying to parse is the element Atlantic.

http://cluster.leaguestat.com/download.php?client_code=ahl&file_path=daily-report/daily-report.html

Comment: What do you want to extract from the page?

Comment: How about we try to parse the first table, Atlantic conference, GP for Portland...the answer should come out to 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several 'atlantic' sections on the page, not sure what you mean by the element Atlantic. Your xpath expression might not be correct, as the 'tr' is not a direct descendant of table (there is a tbody in between). You might want to try `//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]`, as well as the [xpath checker firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1095/) to test expressions.

Comment: Thanks William.  How about we try to parse the first table, Atlantic conference, GP for Portland...the answer should come out to 11.  I think seeing this done will really help me.

Comment: For this, try `/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[td[1]="Portland"]/td[2]`. This selects the first table in the html body section, then the second column in the table row (tr) where the first cell in that row is "Portland".